# How to make multiple pdfs in a loop

Tags: r, pdf, for-loop

I have one loop

```
for (chr in paste('chr',c(seq(1,22),'X','Y'),sep='')){
.
.
pdf ('anna.pdf',paper='a4')
plot(exp,control,xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(0,400),pch=20,col='black',main='Tiles',xlab='exp',ylab 'Control')
dev.off()
 }
```

my problem is that the loop is looking my data for all the chromosomes so in total i should expect in the end 24 pdfs (one per chromosome)

However this not the case....as the program keeps only the last loop's pdf

How can I do that?

What should i write in order to create for every loop one pdf?

Moreover
inside the same loop at a specific position i create a list.txt...

```
write.table(exp.sorted,file="list.txt",append = FALSE ,quote = FALSE,col.names =FALSE,row.names=TRUE,sep="\t")
```

so how can i just fill in the data from each loop in the same txt but without erasing the previous entries????

because as it is now it will create one txt with the last chromosome.

i want a txt with all the chromosomes inside (the data from each chromosome is derived from every time the loop finishes)

Thank you

Best regards
Anna

Comment: Is writing to one single pdf a no-no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're saving it as `anna.pdf` every single time - you need to modify the name of the file so that it varies each iteration of the loop.

For example, you could name it 'anna_[chromosome letter]':

```
pdf(sprintf('anna_%s.pdf',chr),paper='a4')
```

Comment: so if i say     for (chr in paste('chr',c(seq(1,22),'X','Y'),sep='')){
.
.
pdf ('anna_%s.pdf',paper='a4')
plot(exp,control,xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(0,400),pch=20,col='black',main='Tiles',xlab='exp',ylab 'Control')
dev.off()
 } will be ok?

Comment: Yes, except you forgot the `sprintf`. It just makes a new pdf name every loop so you don't save over it every time.

Comment: thank you very much....it works.....however i do have one more question.....inside the same loop at a specific position i create a list.txt...write.table(exp.sorted,file="list.txt",append = FALSE ,quote = FALSE,col.names =FALSE,row.names=TRUE,sep="\t")......so how can i just fill in the data from each loop in the same txt but without erasing the previous entries???? because as it is now it will create one txt with the last chromosome. i want on txt with all the chromosomes inside (the data from each chromosome is derived from every time the loop finishes)

Comment: Why don't you try the `append=TRUE` argument to `write.table` (reading the help files can be  very informative, `?write.table`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to move that pdf()-call and dev.off()-call outside the loop and add the `onefile=TRUE` argument.

```
pdf ('anna.pdf',paper='a4', one.file=TRUE)
for (chr in paste('chr',c(seq(1,22),'X','Y'),sep='')){
.
.

plot(exp,control,xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(0,400),pch=20,
         col='black',main='Tiles',xlab='exp',ylab 'Control')
     }
dev.off()
```

You repeated the question about file overwriting in a separate question and should probably remove it from this one.